# Laravel 5.8 api routes not working behind AWS ELB

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, apache

I am new to Laravel and AWS as well. I have a new Laravel application which is behind an AWS ELB listening on https to client side and http to EC2 instance but when trying to access api routes, it is being blocked due to mixed content.

I have modified my Middleware trusted proxy as seen below

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
}
```

However everything in web route works but not in api routes. Please suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the "does not work"? Did you get any http error? Any output? Any error in the log files?

Comment: Hello this is the error i get           Mixed Content: The page at 'https://elearning.keldeninstitute.com/admin/campus' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://elearning.keldeninstitute.com/api/admin/campus'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Once i added the trusted proxy middle, i stopped seeing the error on web routes but still having the issue with api routes

Comment: Are you requesting the `https` url of your api? Can you update the post with the relevant code that makes the call?